# Tiktok webpage elements can not be found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape tiktok and I can't manage to find the correct element for this button that is in the beginning
[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyIk1.png)

I'm using the `ec.element_to_be_clickable`, and tried to find it using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) with class name, and these two different HTML but I can't manage to find it. I have other issues like this on other buttons
[I'm using the last one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IlYn.png)

I tried this code.

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=browser_options)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com")
try:
    btnPopUp = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-modal"]/div[2]/svg')))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(btnPopUp).click(btnPopUp).perform()
except:
    print("Couldn't find the button :(")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use other way for get the exact code using `selenium IDE`
convert `selenium ide to python` code refer this page [code - export](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export) .
I have also mentioned steps below

1.Open your Selenium IDE test in Firefox/ Chrome browser.

2.Record desired test in the [`Tiktok`](https://www.tiktok.com/) site

3.Click on the "File" menu and select "Export Test Case As".

4.Choose "Python 2 / WebDriver" or "Python / WebDriver" (depending on your Python version) as the export format.

5.Save the exported Python file to your desired location.

6.Open the exported Python file in your preferred text editor or IDE.

7.Update the Python code as needed to suit your specific testing requirements. For example, you may need to modify the test steps, add additional functionality or configure test settings such as the browser type, URL or test data.

8.Run the Python script.